# Jenkins console output with 502 nginx error

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, plugins, kubernetes-helm

For some reason (maybe plugins update) whenever Jenkins calls a groovy method that does not exist it gets an error and when I check console output I get - 502 nginx htttp error.

I suspect its something with plugins since the last error before the http page does not exist is -
Cps.workflow method does not exist

The log itself exists in the file system but not through the UI

Using the latest Jenkins JCASC on Kubernetes